# How do I turn off Hardcore Mode in Mount & Blade?

Tags: mount-and-blade

I regret choosing to play Mount & Blade in hardcore mode. Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: I dont think so.. sorry

Comment: Not being able to turn it off makes it the ultimate hardcore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this, unfortunately, unless someone goes and deciphers the savegame format and figures out where the hardcore mode flag is.

What you can do though, is export the character, then import them into a savegame that is not on hardcore mode.

If you do this, you keep your skills, attributes, money, and experience, but you lose your reputation, honour, army, and items. Its not really a great method, but if you're attached to your character, its a better alternative than starting over.

Here are the steps to take to export your character and import them into a non-hardcore save:

1. Load up your hardcore save
2. Go to the Character tab
3. Click on the Statistics button
4. Click on Export Character
5. Return to the main menu
6. Make a new non-hardcore mode character **with the same name as your old character** (don't worry about the stats and stuff, they get imported)
7. Play through until you get outside the city
8. Go to the character tab
9. Click on the Statistics button
10. Click on Import Character

I know this isn't exactly what you want, but its about as close as you can get.